# Оптимизация SQL-функции под КЛАДР

Tags: c#, база-данных, postgresql, sqlite, sqlite3

Делаю на С# приложение для оптимизации поиска адреса используя КЛАДР. Нашёл статейку для PostgreSQL, а сам планировал сделать все в SQLite и просто таскать с собой эту базу. Вот вопрос - целесообразно ли будет эту статейку переписать под SQLite?

Comment: эту  -  это какую?

Comment: забыл статейку прикрепить, вот она - https://habr.com/en/company/tensor/blog/565850/. Там 2 части

Comment: У КЛАДР есть один существенный недостаток - он устарел на два потопа. ФИАС - на один потоп. Сейчас актуальна [ГАР БД ФИАС](https://www.nalog.gov.ru/opendata/7707329152-fias/). Брать лучше [тут](https://fias.nalog.ru/Updates). Правда, 35 гектар в архиве как-то делают намерение "просто таскать с собой эту базу" плохореализуемым...

Comment: вот поэтому для топорного диплома я выбрал КЛАДР))

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/maxp/6f9ff80825666102f446

В первой части вот этой статьи кладр загоняют в sqlite. Добавьте индексы и можно пользоваться.

!READ FIRST!
http://sqlite.mobigroup.ru/wiki?name=sqlite3-dbf
http://sqlite.mobigroup.ru/wiki?name=sqlite3-kladr

Orig: http://www.opennet.ru/tips/2862_postgresql_kladr.shtml

Конвертация КЛАДР (классификатор адресов России) в формат sqlite.

Скачиваем КЛАДР с официального сайта

```
wget http://www.gnivc.ru/html/gnivcsoft/KLADR/Base.7z
```

Устанавливаем архиватор 7z

```
sudo yum install p7zip
```

Распаковываем архив

```
7za e Base.7z
```

Устанавливаем sqlite

```
sudo yum install sqlite
```

Устанавливаем sqlite3-dbf

```
sudo yum install sqlite3-dbf
```

Запускаем sqlite3

```
sqlite3 my_kladr.db
```

В sqlite загружаем модуль libspatialite

```
.load libspatialite.so.2
```

Импорт данных из КЛАДР в sqlite

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE virt_street_tbl USING VirtualDbf('/home/developer/kladr/STREET.DBF', 'CP866');
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE virt_socrbase_tbl USING VirtualDbf('/home/developer/kladr/SOCRBASE.DBF', 'CP866');
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE virt_kladr_tbl USING VirtualDbf('/home/developer/kladr/KLADR.DBF', 'CP866');
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE virt_flat_tbl USING VirtualDbf('/home/developer/kladr/FLAT.DBF', 'CP866');
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE virt_doma_tbl USING VirtualDbf('/home/developer/kladr/DOMA.DBF', 'CP866');
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE virt_altnames_tbl USING VirtualDbf('/home/developer/kladr/ALTNAMES.DBF', 'CP866');

create table street_tbl as select * from virt_street_tbl;
create table socrbase_tbl as select * from virt_socrbase_tbl;
create table kladr_tbl as select * from virt_kladr_tbl;
create table flat_tbl as select * from virt_flat_tbl;
create table doma_tbl as select * from virt_doma_tbl;
create table altnames_tbl as select * from virt_altnames_tbl;

drop table virt_street_tbl;
drop table virt_socrbase_tbl;
drop table virt_kladr_tbl;
drop table virt_flat_tbl;
drop table virt_doma_tbl;
drop table virt_altnames_tbl;
```

Выходим из sqlite

```
.exit
```

Результат: файл my_kladr.db содержит КЛАДР в формате sqlite.